# CSS text-align:center being ignored

Tags: css

I have the following site that is using a CSS sheet I inheritated from the last dev.

http://bit.ly/1m0LZjZ

Everything seems okay except for the menu.  Originally in the #nav (Line 381 of the style sheet) CSS the width was a fixed 960px.  I changed this to 100% by user request and now cannot get the text to center?

I used text-align:center and also commented out the ul elements use of float:left thinking that was the problem.  What else can I try?

Comment: apply `display: inline-block;` to `div.wrap`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to center the wrapping div, which has width: 950px.

```
#menu-main 
{
   margin: 0 auto;
   overflow: hidden; /* to clear floats */
}
```

EDIT: Think about clearing your floats in `#menu-main`.

For example you could add overflow: hidden on #menu-main, that would clear containing floats.